# ¿Cómo separar valores de un data.frame en nuevas filas?

Tags: r, rstudio

Supongamos que existe un data.frame del estilo:

```
  Tipo Clase
1    1     A
2  2/3     B
3    4     A
4  5/6     B
```

Estoy buscando una forma no engorrosa de que cada vez que en la columna "Tipo" el valor muestre el caracter "/" esa fila se duplique separando ambos valores. Es decir, partiendo del data.frame anterior, obtener esto:

```
  Tipo Clase
1    1     A
2    2     B
3    3     B
4    4     A
5    5     B
6    6     B
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes algunas formas de hacerlo:

#### Con R base

```
s <- strsplit(df$Tipo, split = "/")
data.frame(Tipo = unlist(s),
           Clase = rep(df$Clase, sapply(s, length)))
```

fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15347463/6836377

#### Con `Dplyr`

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(Tipo, Clase,  sep="/")
```

fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27360900/6836377